# Using Java 7 with neo4j on OS X

Tags: java, macos, neo4j

After upgrading Java to 7u45 in system preferences, Neo4j was still warning me about using the wrong version:

```
WARNING! You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
```

I want to use neo4j v2, which doesn't support Java 6, so I needed to fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I started a neo4j 1.9.4 server, and ran `neo4j info`. The output included this line:

```
JAVA_HOME:         /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

So obviously, I needed to set JAVA_HOME. What to set it to? `/usr/libexec/java_home` returns that same directory. The JavaVirtualMachines directory doesn't include any other subfolders. So I tried exploring the java control panel (accessed from system preferences). Under the "Java" tab, click "View", and the path for 7u45 is given:

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

So I tried this, guessing that the `Contents/Home` directories were isomorphic:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
$ neo4j start
WARNING! You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=homebrew
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [34808]... waiting for server to be ready. Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

That's no good.

I searched and found [this post](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/1338n0gsye/neo4j-1-9-m05-java-7-warning-on-my-mac-in-java-7-environment), and on Lasse's advice I edited `/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/1.9.4/libexec/bin/utils`. I added two lines:

```
 # check if running Oracle JDK 7, warn if not
 checkjvmcompatibility() {
+  echo $JAVACMD
+  $JAVACMD -version
   $JAVACMD -version 2>&1 | egrep -q "Java HotSpot\\(TM\\) (64-Bit Server|Server|C
 lient) VM"
   if [ $? -eq 1 ]
   then
     echo "WARNING! You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7."
   else
     $JAVACMD -version 2>&1 | egrep -q "java version \"1.7"
     if [ $? -eq 1 ]
     then
       echo "WARNING! You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7."
     fi
   fi
 }
```

And tried again:

```
$ neo4j start
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java
bin/utils: line 349: /Library/Internet: No such file or directory
WARNING! You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
```

It looks like the space in the path is confusing. I tried to escape it, but my first approach failed:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME="'/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home'"
$ neo4j start
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home'/bin/java
```

And then I decided that the simple (not necessarily nice) solution was just to make a symlink:

```
$ cd /Library/
$ sudo ln -s Internet\ Plug-Ins/ Internet-Plug-Ins
$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet-Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

At this point `neo4j start` ran correctly; and I managed to upgrade to v2.0.0-M6 and it still worked.

Comment: Could you try downloading this file and put it into your bin directory and then try setting JAVA_HOME to the path with spaces in - https://raw.github.com/mneedham/neo4j/54f47c41164d9c317aefefc2a37149bac283adda/packaging/standalone/src/main/distribution/shell-scripts/bin/neo4j. And then let me know if it's able to start correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install java JDK 1.7.x on your Max OS and then

Run this to see where is the latest java JDK is.

$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V

```
1.7.0_45, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-462, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-462, i386: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

This case my latest version is 1.7.0_45

$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home

$ bin/neo4j start

It works for me.

Comment: That doesn't find JDK 1.7.x for me, just the 1.6.0 that was used by default.

Comment: If you want to change every programs to use JDK 1.7.x by default
$ vim .bash_profile
Press i (to insert text)
add line -->
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
Press ESC then type :wq

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to be helpful, but did you read my comment on this answer, or the answer I posted above? I know how to edit text files, I already set JAVA_HOME in my profile, and /usr/libexec/java_home *still* doesn't find JDK 1.7.x.