# neo4j can't find java

Tags: java, macos, neo4j, homebrew

After `brew install neo4j` and downloading latest jdk from Oracle on OS X Mavericks, neo4j won't start, saying it can't find java. Most similar problems seem to be from having `$JAVA_HOME` incorrectly set, which I think I have set correctly.

```
~  export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) 
~  export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
~  echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home
~  neo4j start
ERROR: Unable to find java. (Cannot execute drip)
* Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) 7 to run Neo4j Server. Download "Java Platform (JDK) 7" from:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
* Please see http://docs.neo4j.org/ for Neo4j Server installation instructions.
```

I'm guessing something's wrong with my java; any ideas on illuminating java to my neo4j?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713577/using-java-7-with-neo4j-on-os-x

Comment: While it was a different issue, it got me on the right track to solving it, so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had `export JAVACMD=drip` incorrectly set in my zshrc file from a previous installation. Unsetting it fixed the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue.  How do you do reset this?  Thank you!